# how to change the position of the button in the flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem, it's not difficult, but I can't solve it. I have a task book program. At the top is the word "task", this word is in the middle as needed. But there is also a button (add). The problem is that I can't put it closer to the center, to the word "task"! I'll be grateful if someone can help me move this button to the center to the level of the word "task"

My code :

```
Container(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 3,
                          child: Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
                            child: Text(("Tasks"),
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 70.0,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          )
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: FlatButton(
                          textColor: Colors.black,
                          color: Colors.white12,
                          child: Text('+',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 70.0,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          )),
                          onPressed:  () {
                            if (textController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                              WidgetList.add(
                                  new ListItem(textController.text, false));
                              setState(() {
                                valText = true;
                                textController.clear();

                              });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                              setState(() {
                                valText = false;
                              });
                            }
                          },
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 10.0, 30, 10.0),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                        ),)


                    ],
                  ),

                ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to not use **FlatButton** cause' it is deprecated, and as you use an icon to create a button, use **IconButton** instead :

```
   Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, // this is to center both
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text(
            "Tasks",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 24.0,
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            color: Colors.black,
            iconSize: 28,
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add_outlined),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Ok, the contraints in the **IconButton**, in less words it helps you to be close between the **Text** and the **Icon** and delete the padding (but not all), aaaand if you add **padding: EdgeInsets.zero**, literally it deletes all the padding to zero. Try to add some padding, to fix the "closer"